# onRestoreInstanceState not being called

Tags: android

Follow on from a previous question

One first screen activity I am clicking a button and doing this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, NewClass.class);
intent.putExtra("value1", value1);  
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Value is passed to new activity and is used in the `onCreate()`-method

On new Activity I am saving the state when I click back button

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // the UI component values are saved here.
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Activity state saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //super.onBackPressed();
    Intent intent = new Intent(RoundScoring.this, MainMenu.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    startActivity(intent);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Back Button Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

On the first screen again I am clicking a different button with the following :

```
Intent intentContiune = new Intent(MainMenu.this, NewClass.class);
intentContiune.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intentContiune);
```

The Activty is loaded but always fails as the value has not been set. I wrote a `onRestorInstanceState` to re-populate the value from the bundle but it is never fired. Can someone say what I am doing wrong

Thanks for your time

UPDATE

```
@Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "returnstate called");
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        value = savedInstanceState.getString("value");


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Application

`yourApplication.java`

```
public yourApplication extends Application {
    String Value;
    public synchronized String getValue(){
        return Value;
    }
    public synchronized void setValue(String Value){
        this.Value = Value;
    }
}
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application android:name="yourApplication" ...
```

Now You can save value anywhere using:

***SAVE***

```
((yourApplication) getApplicationContext()).setValue("something");
```

***LOAD***

```
((yourApplication) getApplicationContext()).getValue();
```

Comment: Tried this but still is not called

Comment: but onResume cannot be used with bundle. As you can see I am saving a value away on save

Comment: You are saving UI components.. This is not needed since your Activity is still alive?

Comment: Are you saying then to remove the onsaveinstance and onrestore and just have onrusume() instead. The value will be kept when it the second button is pressed

Comment: Yes of course! But I think Your activity will be recreated if the first button was pressed!? right?

Comment: At the moment I am value = getIntent().getStringExtra("value"); within the oncreate(). moving that to the onrsume does not get eh value back

Comment: @Sherif let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2404/discussion-between-james-dudley-and-sherif)

Comment: Thanks, This worked great in the end, Not have had to use either onsavedinstance or restore

Answer (score 0):

The `onRestoreInstanceState` get's called when activity reinitializes not after activity starts.....so on starting activity it will not be called ...

If you are saving some data then you can use sharedPreference for situation like this....

Comment: trouble is I will want to add an ArrayList to the bundle and do not belive you can do this with shared prefreences

Comment: then you should use Sqlite database of android

Answer (score 0):

`onRestoreInstanceState()` is very tricky. I suggest you to use SharedPreferences

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: trouble is I will want to add an ArrayList to the bundle and do not belive you can do this with shared prefreences

Comment: Workaround it. Let say if you have ArrayList of strings, you can save the preferences by iterating thru the list and putting `int i = 0;
for(String s: list){ editor.putString("pref"+i, s); i++; } ` and then just call `.commit();` This logic will work the same for loading preferences.

Comment: Yes, you cannot put entire bundle or anything different from bool/string/int/long/double

Answer (score 0):

Check your

> AndroidManifest.xml

It should **not** contain

> android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"

Answer (score 0):

The system calls onRestoreInstanceState only if there is a saved state to restore in your Activity. Precisely when the Activity has been killed by the system due to lack of resources it's used to preserve the state saved in onSaveInstanceState.

If you want to save some information and have them available at every moment then just use SharedPreferences.